# unable to start Fiware Cygnus as a service

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I installed fiware cygnus using RPM on my centOS 7 but I can't start it as service. I got the following error:

```
[root@localhost cygnus]# sudo service cygnus start
Starting cygnus (via systemctl):  Job for cygnus.service failed. See 'systemctl status cygnus.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [ÉCHOUÉ]
    [root@localhost cygnus]# systemctl status cygnus.service -l
    cygnus.service - SYSV: cygnus
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ven. 2015-07-31 19:11:10 CEST; 2s ago
      Process: 5750 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

juil. 31 19:11:08 localhost cygnus[5750]: /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf: ligne34: mongo-channel : commande introuvable
juil. 31 19:11:08 localhost su[5756]: (to root) root on none
juil. 31 19:11:10 localhost cygnus[5750]: Starting Cygnus 1...  [ÉCHOUÉ]
juil. 31 19:11:10 localhost systemd[1]: cygnus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
juil. 31 19:11:10 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: cygnus.
juil. 31 19:11:10 localhost systemd[1]: Unit cygnus.service entered failed state.
```

not sure what to put as name of the agent in the configuration file: cygnus_instance_1.conf since it did not reconize the agent name

```
# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Fluleters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME= mongo-channel
```

Here is my complete configuration files:
cygnus_instance_1.conf

```
#####
#
# Configuration file for apache-flume
#
#####
# Copyright 2014 Telefonica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

# Who to run cygnus as. Note that you may need to use root if you want
# to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024)
CYGNUS_USER=root

# Where is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Fluleters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME= /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng
#mongo-channel

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

agent_1.conf

```
# Copyright 2014 Telefónica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/agent.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mongo-sink
cygnusagent.channels = mongo-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf


# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
# FQDN/IP:port where the MongoDB server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = 192.168.1.40:27017
# a valid user in the MongoDB server (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username = mongo_username
# password for the user above (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password = xxxxxxxx
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
# prefix pro the MongoDB collections
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false

#=============================================
# mongo-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

UPDATES after @frb response:
I updated my cygnus_instance_1.conf @frb response but unfortuantly as I got the following error:

```
 systemctl status cygnus.service -l
cygnus.service - SYSV: cygnus
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer. 2015-08-05 17:22:09 CEST; 3s ago
  Process: 3338 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

août 05 17:22:07 localhost cygnus[3338]: /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf: ligne24: cygnus : commande introuvable
août 05 17:22:07 localhost cygnus[3338]: /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf: ligne34: cygnusagent : commande introuvable
août 05 17:22:07 localhost su[3345]: (to cygnus) root on none
août 05 17:22:07 localhost cygnus[3338]: Starting Cygnus 1...  bash: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid: Permission non accordée
août 05 17:22:09 localhost cygnus[3338]: cat: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
août 05 17:22:09 localhost cygnus[3338]: [ÉCHOUÉ]
août 05 17:22:09 localhost cygnus[3338]: rm: impossible de supprimer « /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
août 05 17:22:09 localhost systemd[1]: cygnus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
août 05 17:22:09 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: cygnus.
août 05 17:22:09 localhost systemd[1]: Unit cygnus.service entered failed state.
```

Looking to the above error I saw that it can't find the file "/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid" so I created an empty file to bypass this error but I got a new one:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl start cygnus.service
Job for cygnus.service failed. See 'systemctl status cygnus.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl status cygnus.service -l
cygnus.service - SYSV: cygnus
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer. 2015-08-05 17:24:08 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 3445 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cygnus start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

août 05 17:24:06 localhost systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: cygnus...
août 05 17:24:06 localhost cygnus[3445]: /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf: ligne24: cygnus : commande introuvable
août 05 17:24:06 localhost cygnus[3445]: /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf: ligne34: cygnusagent : commande introuvable
août 05 17:24:06 localhost su[3452]: (to cygnus) root on none
août 05 17:24:06 localhost cygnus[3445]: Starting Cygnus 1...  bash: /var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid: Permission non accordée
août 05 17:24:08 localhost cygnus[3445]: [ÉCHOUÉ]
août 05 17:24:08 localhost systemd[1]: cygnus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
août 05 17:24:08 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: cygnus.
août 05 17:24:08 localhost systemd[1]: Unit cygnus.service entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `agent_1.conf` configuration, the `AGENT_NAME` within `cygnus_instance_1.conf` must be `cygnusagent`. I.e.:

```
AGENT_NAME = cygnusagent
```

In addition, the `CYGNUS_USER` should be `cygnus`,  since this is the user the RPM creates when installing the software.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I updated my config file but I got new errors, I edited my question with logs.

Comment: Did you configured the `CYGNUS_USER` as `cygnus`? Can you check this user exists (it should has been created by the RPM when installing)?

Comment: yes the user exists "cygnus:x:990:988:Cygnus user account:/home/cygnus:/bin/bash" and I can start cygnus as a dependant application using "/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console " but still can't start it as a service :(

Comment: `/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid` is the file where the user `cygnus` writes the process ID (PID) for the application (this is needed in order to stop it, for instance). It seems the user `cygnus` (which exists, as commented) is not allowed to write to that path. Who is the owner and what at are the permissions for `/var/run/cygnus/cygnus_1.pid`?

Comment: I found that cygnus_1.pid have the following owner and permission "-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0  6 août  09:37 cygnus_1.pid" so I change it to "-rwxrwxrwx. 1 cygnus root 0  6 août  09:37 cygnus_1.pid" and I tryied to restart cygnus as a service but I got the last error mentionned above, he can't recogonise "cygnus" and "cygnusagent"